# Does the class of groups with all non-abelian composition factors contain some rich subclass?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, group-extensions

I would like to know some well known subclass of the following group class:

$\mathcal{G}=$class of all groups with all composition factors are non abelian.

Obviously $\mathcal{G}$ contains the direct(and semidirect) product of non abelian simple groups.

My question is, does $\mathcal{G}$ contains any other rich subclass or a finite set of groups ?

Comment: See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301784/) for examples of this type that cannot be constructed by repeatedly using direct and semidirect products of nonabelian simple groups.